# How to force to restart firefox in a clean way?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, firefox, firefox-extensions

Many times when I upgrade the system under Linux, *firefox* pops up a window suggesting to restart the program in order to make effective all the changes.

When I ignore that windows because of an urgent duty in a second time I'm not able to find it again.

Of course I know it's always possible to exit and restart it manually; in Linux to kill the process with `pkill firefox && sync && firefox &`, with or without a brutal `-9`.
In a similar way in Windows it is possible to use the Task Manager...

**What I was searching for is an internal solution, a clean one, possibly  system independent**.
How to force to restart firefox in a clean way ?

---

ps> It is possible that when updated external third parties programs *firefox* will not prompt for restarting, even if it should be recommended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to quickly restart Firefox Quantum (V57 or up)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1283297/is-it-possible-to-quickly-restart-firefox-quantum-v57-or-up)

Comment: @user, I don't know if it was you, but someone is asking to close this question (2015) as a duplicate of another question written later (2018)... `8-)`...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:**
Now it is possible to do it directly in the url bar, asking for the special page **about:restartrequired**

```
about:restartrequired
```

It opens a page with a button to restart firefox that should preserve pages, tabs and windows.

[image]

**Fast *Internal* answer:**
Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, write `restart` in the opened bar, then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
On old versions, e.g. the *41.0.2*, it was needed to write the word **true** too: `restart true`.

**Some words more:**
It's possible to force Firefox to restart through the [Developer Toolbar](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI), usually accessible via <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> or via menu (`Firefox/Tools >> Web Developer >> Developer Toolbar` in the English version).

A bar will be opened in the bottom of the page where it will be possible to write the command

```
restart
```

It is possible to use `restart --nocache true` or `restart --nocache false` in order to force it the refresh of the tabs content or to use the local cached instead.
In a similar way it is possible to force the safe mode upon restart.

> Synopsis: restart [--nocache] [--safemode]
>
> Restart Firefox
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> [--nocache] (boolean, required)
> Disables loading content from cache upon restart
> [--safemode] (boolean, required)
> Enables Safe Mode upon restart
> ```

- It works on Firefox 45.0.2.  For the old synopsis check in the [history of this answer](https://superuser.com/posts/992383/revisions).

---

**An alternative way; pick a firefox Add on:**
Another option *was* to pick one of the many add-ons available for Firefox from the [add-on page](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=restart&platform=all), such as [Restart Button](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restart-button/), or [Restart](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/re-start/?src=search)... that can add a button or a line in the the menu. However these examples are not compatible with Firefox 57 or later.

Comment: This answer is expiring. In the next stable release (Firefox 62), the Developer Toolbar is removed. None of the restarting add-ons are working in latest Firefox. The only way since Firefox 62 is to go to `about:profiles` page, as [shown here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1184755#answer-1096361).

Comment: @FranklinYu The answer is updated...

Comment: Working on 94.0.

Answer (score 7):

In Firefox 62, the browser CLI (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>) was removed ([change tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1461970), [release notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/62)). I found two ways to restart Firefox 62 or newer:

### Using `about:profiles`

1. Navigate to `about:profiles` in the URL bar.
2. At the top-right corner of the page, click `Restart normally...`.

### Keyboard shortcut in browser console

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> on Mac) to open the Browser Console.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on Mac) to restart the browser.